# Testing Discord.py bot with another Discord.py bot / Mocking

Tags: python, testing, discord

So, I'm trying to UnitTest my bot, but I'm facing a problem. At first, I thought I'll just write UnitTests for commands I have. After doing some research I came to the conclusion, that to achieve that - I will have to basically Mock everything: ctx, server, Bot, DataBase (probably), and so on. Then I got genius idea, to use another bot to call the commands in the first bot and just look at the answers I get, but after trying and failing to achieve that: the bot receives message from another bot, sends message to:

```
await client.process_commands(message)
```

which should recognize message as command and run it, but not a single command I tried gets activated, so I came to the conclusion, that bots probably can't activate other bot commands.

So my questions basically would be: 
Can bots send commands to other bots, if yes - how to achieve that?
If mocking is the only way - where should I start and do anyone have any examples already done or could point my in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a bit strange. Approach you introduce is not unit test, it's integration test. Unit test only check single functionality, unit, in separation. I think you should not try to mock so many different dependencies. Just write proper integration test which check if many parts works well together.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't have an `on_message` event directly on the bot.
**(Not `Cog.listener`, but `bot.event`)**

In that case, dpy's default on_message handler **ignores all bot messages**, which is desirable, but in your case, you can override the handler with something similar to:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message:discord.Message):
    if message.author.bot and message.author.id != TESTER_BOT_ID: # Replace this
        return
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Make sure to replace TESTER_BOT_ID with the user id of the bot that you use for testing.

This would only allow that bot to interact with your bot, and other bots would end up being ignored.